# How to Make Magento Show The Entire SQL Error

Tags: mysql, magento

Every once in awhile I am programming something in Magento and I get a MySQL error. When the exception displays on the screen it only displays the first few characters of the query that it was trying to execute.

Is there a way to get Magento to display the entire query in the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set on the debug mode in mysql adapter (Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)

```
/**
 * Write SQL debug data to file
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_debug               = true;
```

Go to file (var/debug/sql.txt), find the exception get query and execute it in mysql tool.
The problem is the PDO returns only part of the error, the full error message you can see only when you execute your query in some tool.

Comment: I love this tip, I wish it was wider utilised.

Comment: This is an awesome tip. The edit below only captures the failing sql however this is needed to capture queries that lead up to failure.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo#_execute` method to include `$this->_stmt->queryString` in the thrown exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a module that pretty prints the SQL as well:

https://github.com/kalenjordan/pretty-sql-exception

Comment: should you package vendor/jdorn/sql-formatter/lib/SqlFormatter.php with your git repo?

Comment: @JaseC, I opted to use composer for dependency management: https://github.com/kalenjordan/pretty-sql-exception/blob/master/composer.json#L15